# How do I undo a git svn dcommit?

Tags: version-control, git-svn

I made a mistake in a `git svn dcommit` and would like to undo the commit. (I was actually trying to push to a branch, but pushed to trunk instead.) How can I do this with git-svn?

Comment: try here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318777/undo-a-particular-commit-in-git

Comment: So the idea would be use ``git revert <commit_hash>`` and then ``git svn dcommit``?

Comment: Yep... write that as an answer and I'll vote for you.

Answer (score 9):

Subversion provides no means to *undo* a commit like Git does. Lately I learned, that using TortoiseSVN you can retroactively modify Subversion commit messages, but Subversion commits themselves are more or less final.

So what you need to to is a new commit which reverts your changes using  `git revert <commit_hash>` and then a following `git svn dcommit` as you already pointed out in your comments.

Unfortunately this will not help to avoid conflicts in the modified files to others, even that these two commits in sum effectively do nothing.