# Undo or remove changes from a previous Git commit

Tags: git, git-revert, git-rewrite-history

Suppose I have a list of commits:
`A > B > C > D > E`  , how can I remove from history the changes made in C , to have `A > B > D > E` ?

Comment: You need to clarify whether or not you want to keep C in your history or not, or if you merely want to undo its changes in your current version of the code base, and you don't care if C is still in your history. Does it even matter to you?

Comment: See also [Undo a particular commit in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2318777/456814).

Comment: In this case, I do not care about C commit,  I drop it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always revert the changes.

```
git revert C
```

If you want to rewrite history, this is what `rebase` is for. You need to:

```
git rebase -i A
```

Then remove C from the list of the commits.

**Longer explanation:**

First option reverts the change by creating a new commit which is the opposite of the original commit. So the repository would look like:

A > B > C > D > E > C`

Where C` is opposite of C. Basically, same as `patch --reverse`

Second option changes the history. `rebase` allows you to select specific commits, change order of commits, and much more. I suggest reading [git-rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).
The `-i` flag is for interactive mode which let the user edit the list of commits before rebasing.

If you remove C from the list of commits and perform the rebase, the actual output would be

A > B > D > E

You have no longer history of C in the branch.

Note: In both cases you may have conflicts in the process.
In first case because you are applying C` over E, and in the second case because you applying D over B.

Comment: Tx Igal, Can you elaborate your answer a bit?

Comment: Done. Edited my answer.

Comment: You should mention that rebase shouldn't be used if other people also have commit C in their history. Or if those people are okay with having to also rebase/redo their work on top of the rewritten commit, then rebase is ok, but you don't just rebase shared history lightly, in any case.

Answer (score 2):

try `git revert C`

...and best also read `man git-revert`

Answer (score 2):

*You can't do it* **and** get `A > B > D > E`. 
You will always end up with `A > B > D' > E'`

To remove the changes introduced in C you can use

```
git rebase --onto <newbase> <oldbase> <commit/branch>
```

in your case:

```
git rebase --onto B C E
```

This will place changes introduced in `D..E` from the old base `C` onto the new base `B` (if you do not hit any conflicts) resulting in

```
A > B > D' > E'
```

It is *important* to note that `D` and `E` get new sha IDs resulting in `D'` and `E'` so if you already published `C`, `D` or `E` use the revert approach (`git revert C`) or you might mess up other peoples history.

Comment: So this answer is a little misleading. While it is true that D and E are rewritten to have new sha IDs, the *changes* introduced by each commit are still the same.

Comment: hi.. thanks, tried to reword my answer to reflect that it is still possible to remove changes made in `C` but not end up with the same sha ID for `E`