# Revert a specific commit from a merged branch that has already been pushed

Tags: git, github, merge, revert

I was just reading the post below and I had a question I was hoping someone would know the answer to.

[How to revert a merge commit that's already pushed to remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch)

So I know that I can completely revert a merge commit from my master by specifying its parent branch in the git revert -m command. My question is can I revert a single commit from that merged branch rather than the entire branch.

For example I branch from master to feature_1 branch. I make 14 commits on the feature_1 branch and merge back to my master, which I then push.

How would I go about removing commit 7 of the merged branch from the master  while leaving the other 13 in the master. Hopefully its possible and thanks in advance for any replies or comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2318777/4286990.

Comment: Thanks vatsal, I made the assumption that reverting commits that were inside a merge would be harder to do than reverting a normal commit because of the -m option needed when reverting a merge. Turns out I was wrong. Thanks again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step 1: Identify the `<sha1>` of the commit you'd like to revert.

Step 2: Do this on the master branch:

```
$ git revert <sha1>
```

That will create a new commit that revert the commit identified by `<sha1>`.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb, I just assumed because it was part of a merge I would need to take that into consideration. My apologies for asking such a silly question.