# Unable to push reverted file to repository after git reset

Tags: git, git-reset

*Note - I am new to understanding the git reset command, so I am not sure if it is the right command for what I want to do, which is very simple.*

I wanted to undo the changes made in the last git push.
So, I ran the following reset command to go back to the desired commit hash (one before the undesired commit hash)-

```
git reset <last desired commit hash> <file name>
```

After this, there were no changes to file as such (working directory). But, `git status` showed that the file had been modified.

```
 modified:   <filename>
```

On doing `git stash` now, the working directory file was modified. But, I do not see an option to push the changes to remote repository. Git pull also shows no changes.

Comment: (1) It may not be the right command, at least, not as used. (2) Possible duplicates include http://stackoverflow.com/q/927358/1256452 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2318777/1256452 (3) Changes aren't made in pushes; changes are made in the work-tree, and then committed as a new snapshot through `git add` and `git commit`.

Comment: `git stash` will have stashed your changes, so they won't be available to push. Prior to the `git stash`, what were the results of the `diff` on the file?

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push

Comment: @thebluefox the `diff` on the working directory using a UI tool showed the desired version in the left hand side and the undesired version on right. I finally did the following after taking a fresh `pull` - git reset --hard <old-commit-id-correct one-before-error-commit>
git push -f <remote-name> <branch-name>

This removed the undesired commit completely from the commit log.

Comment: @SandeepanNath you got the answer you expected?? :))

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your doubts in your approach with this.

- `git reset <last desired commit hash> <file name>`. This will restore your desired file(`<file name>`) into the version specified by `<last desired commit>`.  And you will still be remained in the current branch.
- If the file you specified had any difference between the version you had and the version you restored, soon after you executed previous command this kind of a text should appear. 
  `Unstaged changes after reset:
   M  <file name>`
- You can verify it by the following command. `git diff <file name>`. Then it will show the change happened.
- `git stash` will remove any un-staged commit. So obviously after `git stash`you can't commit or push since there are no any changes. And `git pull` would not work either. Reason is your local branch will not go behind with commits by `git reset`. So it has all the commits in remote branch. So there's no new commits to be pulled by `git pull`.
- You can try followings. Do `git stash apply`. So your file will again go to the state of last desired commit. Verify the changes by `git diff <file name>`. Then commit & push.
- If your expected change was not there when you check the diff, the problem should be with some other thing, not version controlling. :))