# How to revert an old commit without loosing all subsequent changes/commits?

Tags: git, git-revert

In my project we need to revert an old commit which upgraded version of Protobuf library to 3 back to 2 as our counterparts are not ready to upgrade yet. This upgrade was made around 24 commits ago.
For now I manually made those changes and pushed in a new commit. Is there a way I can `git revert` that commit and still keep the changes from all the newer 22 commits?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2318777/5987698) may be relevant.

Comment: `git revert <commit>` should undo only the changes introduced by that commit. Did you encounter any error or problem with `git revert`?

Comment: this was just what I was looking for @GoodDeeds. Thanks