# How to undo faulty commit without delete

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-commit

Instead of deleting a faulty commit from master branch, is there a good way to add a new commit on top that somehow reverts the same changes as the faulty commit introduced?

In other words, we merged a commit that introduced a regression so we want to "undo that commit" but we'd rather not delete the commit somehow since then existing feature branches would have to be forced merged/pushed to master.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undo a particular commit in Git that's been pushed to remote repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318777/undo-a-particular-commit-in-git-thats-been-pushed-to-remote-repos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [git-revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

```
git revert <commit>
```

It creates a new commit that negates the changes the specified commit introduced.